# if cell blank leave cell blank if a number categorize

Tags: excel

I need to come up with a formula that leaves cells blank when no value is entered and if value is entered it needs to categorize it in 3 levels, like in example:

[image: categorizing lab data]]

I have use following formula but it reads blank cells as 0:

```
=IF(AND($AF4>=0,$AF4<=100),"1","0")
```

Comment: Just add another IF to test if the cell is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IF (ISBLANK (AF4),"",IF(AND($AF4>=0,$AF4<=100),"1","0"))
```